# Error " Specified location is not a valid domain"

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, server

I'm trying to add a Glassfish 4.0 server to an eclipse Spring Tool Suite project (3.6.2).

-Glassfish 4.0 server is running and working (I can see on the localhost console)
-Glassfish for 4.0 are installed in my sts

I have no problem with the first and second panel (server path location), but with the third, I get an error " Specified location is not a valid domain". I don't understand this error, because this is the good location and the good name for my domain (I could verify it with the server log). I've tested with the browse panel and that didn't work too.

So, I'm don't why I get this error.
Thanks 
Ps: Sorry I can't post pic

Answer (score 1):

Look at your install directory, find file like this:
`C:\tools\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat`
run `asadmin.bat`, enter command:

```
create-domain --help
```

to see document.

```
create-domain your_domain_name
```

to create new your_domain_name domain.
Check list domains, use `asadmin` enter command:

```
list-domains
```

Reference: [GlassFish Server Documentation](https://glassfish.java.net/documentation.html). You should also check your [GlassFish Tools for Luna](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-luna) inside Spring Tools suite.

Answer (score 0):

You must to add a password to your admin user. Eclipse mistake. Eclipse doesn't recognise the domain without admin password

When you create the domain, add a admin user and a password and Eclipse doesn't complain any more