# Specified location is not a valid domain. -docker

Tags: docker, eclipse, server, glassfish-4

We used Docker to build a development environment
If you try to work with an existing server

Specified location is not a valid domain.

The error appears.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA6CH.png)

I've tried all the other answers, but it's impossible because it's a method using a local server.

[Error " Specified location is not a valid domain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715383/error-specified-location-is-not-a-valid-domain)